# OrientDB Fetch Plan/Strategies with Tinkerpop

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've been using Tinkerpop 2.6 with OrientDB to manipulate the graph, and I'm running into some performance problems.

I suspect the issue has to do with the fact that OrientDB lazy loads records. In my case, I'm fetching adjacent vertices by two different labels, adding a new edge, and setting a property.

I know OrientDB recommends paying attention to fetch plans, but I see no clear way of doing so via the OrientGraph or Tinkerpop. Note that I use the OrientGraphFactory to get transaction database instances, and I don't see it in there either.

How can I use fetch plans with OrientGraphs and Tinkerpop?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you connected to OrientDB in remote or plocal?

Comment: @Lvca I'm connected to OrientDB in remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OrientDB SQL. Example:

```
graph.command(new OCommandSQL("select from V where name = 'Luca' fetchplan *:3"))
     .execute();
```

Comment: Hi Luca, thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately that doesn't really help me since I'm trying to traverse my graph with Tinkerpop. Is there some way I can set the fetchplan before making my tinkerpop queries?

Comment: If you cast Graph instance to OrientBaseGraph, it works.